# Stack depth limit exceeded PostgreSQL insert trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, psql

I'm trying to create a simple trigger that inserts a row into the friend table with inverted values, so when (1,2) is inserted (2,1) is also inserted, but I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into friend(ID1,ID2) values (NEW.ID2, NEW.ID1)"
PL/pgSQL function friend_add() line 2 at SQL statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.friend_add()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
COST 100
AS $BODY$begin
insert into friend(ID1,ID2) values (NEW.ID2, NEW.ID1);
return new;
end
end;$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER friend_add
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.friend
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.friend_add();
```

Here are my function and trigger definions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an infinite loop: you insert ID1-ID2, then the trigger inserts ID2-ID1, which is caught by the trigger that again inserts ID1-ID2 etc.

You need to do the insert once only. The simplest (and propably the safest) would be to have a unique constraint on ID1-ID2, and to do an upsert:

```
insert into friend(ID1,ID2) values (NEW.ID2, NEW.ID1) ON CONFLICT (ID1,ID2) DO NOTHING;
```